# Does Kernighan-Lin algorithm guarantee its partitions to be a connected graph?

Tags: graphs, partitions

Currently I am experimenting with Kernighan-Lin algorithm to produce coarse representation of navigation mesh for hierarchical pathfinding.

Based on the use case, my requirement is that partitions produced are a connected graph on its own.

For example, a bisection of the below grid

```
x--x--x--x--x--x
|  |  |  |  |  |
x--x--x--x--x--x
|  |  |  |  |  |
x--x--x--x--x--x
```

Should produce something along the lines of

```
a--a--a--b--b--b
|  |  |  |  |  |
a--a--a--b--b--b
|  |  |  |  |  |
a--a--a--b--b--b
```

where all nodes in partition A can be reached from a node in partition A without crossing a node in partition B.

However in quite a number of tests, I am getting disconnected partitions such as.

```
a--b--b--b--a--a
|  |  |  |  |  |
a--b--b--b--a--a
|  |  |  |  |  |
b--b--b--a--a--a
```

I am not able to judge if this is a bug in my code or whether the Kernighan-Lin algorithm by nature does not guarantee connected partitions.

I know that KL algorithm works towards a locally optimal solution for minimum cut, but does the algorithm not guarantee connected partitions?

Comment: Do *your* edges have an elaborate cost model, or are all of them same/unit cost? If you can, refer to a description of the *Kernighan-Lin algorithm* - in en.wikipedia, nothing suggesting ***connected** partitions* caught my eye.

Comment: I've been testing with both unit weights and distance between navigation mesh face centroids as weights, but both

Comment: Ran out of time for above comment...

I've been testing with both unit weights and distance between navigation mesh face centroids as weights, but both approach yielded disconnected partitions. I have read the Wikipedia page but "partitioning" intuitively suggests that a partition is a single contained partition... It would be unintuitive if Kernighan-Lin bisection can produce more than two disconnected groups. If it is the case that KL can produce disconnected single partition, I am surprised I can't seem to find any resources describing its limitations.

Comment: (I went the other way just to find *connected mincut partitioning* hard to find.)

Comment: Do you mean that mincut partitioning in academic context usually implies that the partitions are disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

The Kernighan-Lin algorithm tries to find a partition.  As far as I can tell, the partition it finds might or might not be connected; I don't see any guarantee that it will output a connected partition.  There is also no guarantee that it finds the optimal partition.  Even if the optimal partition is connected, I don't think there is any guarantee that the Kernighan-Lin algorithm will output a connected partition.